Unable to access first element of array in mongodb pipeline
My pipeline intermediate result looks like this:
[
  {
    "claim": [
      {
        "_id": "1-8101-2023-0445722",
        "data_accadimento": {"$date": "2023-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "index": 180,
        "rainValue": 26.290000000000006,
        "hailValue": 0,
        "inundationValue": -1.7223792589410434,
        "windValue": 5.940000057220459,
        "lightningValue": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "claim": [
      {
        "_id": "1-8101-2023-0445722",
...
]

I am trying to access rainValue inside a $project stage by doing:
{
    $project: {
        claimRainValue: "$claim.0.rainValue"
    }
  },

However the result is an empty array.
Why? The number of elements inside the claim array is one.

claimRainValue: { $arrayElemAt: ["$claim.rainValue", 0] }

A canonical way would be using $first

Why $claim.0 is not working?

@asant-leitha The $project operator is slightly different with the projection you used in a plain find operation. Your index-based syntax will work there. However in aggregation, your syntax is more interpreted as accessing field 0 from claim field. As the claim array does not have such field, you cannot achieve your expected result
